# Use ID column of DataGridView as source of query of another DataGridView

Tags: linq, data-binding, datagridview, c#-3.0

I use LINQ to query my MSSQL 2005 database. I want to show several fields of some tables in one DataGridView. The selection of a row of the DataGridView should result in showing results in another DataGridView based on a column which is not shown in any DataGridView (it is an ID attribute).

What is a good way to accomplish this?

---

### My Ideas of Possible Solutions

#### Bind to an Anonymous Type

I would bind my DataGridView to a BindingSource, which is bound to the result of an anonymous LINQ query (anonymous type). To get the ID to build up the relation to the second DataGridView, I would use reflections.

#### Bind to a Specific Type

I would create a class which holds all fields I want to show in my DataGridView and additionally the ID field. The BindindSource would bind to an instance of this specific class.

I want to avoid this method, because I would have to create one class for each DataGridView I use in my application and I would have to maintain three parts, the class, the LINQ query and the DataGridView columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to ensure the ID attribute is a DataKey on the first Gridview.  Add a RowSelecting event to the first Gridview, use the ID attribute for that Row as a parameter for the second Gridview, and DataBind.

If you are trying to display different data depending on the Row that is selected (i.e. data could come from a few different database tables) then I'd suggest you create a GridView for each of those tables, and in your RowSelecting event identify which GridView to bind & display.

It's much simpler and clearer to have static GridViews than it is so dynamically create and format them.

EDIT:  So if you have n:m:l structure and want to display all l for a particular n, you need to run a subselect such as 
`SELECT * FROM l WHERE l.m_id IN
 (SELECT m_id FROM m WHERE m.n_id = n_value)`

So in summary:

1. Read up on DataKey property.  This
   will help you store the n value (the
   id of the n table).
2. Read up on
   RowSelecting event.  This will allow
   you to catch the n value for the
   selected Row.
3. Run a query similar
   to the above and bind your second
   GridView to the resulting
   DataSource.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "ensure the ID attribute is a DataKey on the first Gridview"?

Comment: I don't want to have an extra DataGridView for each relation. I have a n:m:l relation and want to show *all* possible l's if the n was specified.

Comment: A DataKey is a way of storing additional values for a grid without displaying them.  Think of it as a hidden field.  Alternatively, you could use a hidden field!